# Checking the text alignment of a cell in Excel using Word VBA 2007

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I know that the following Word VBA 2007 code

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Book1").Cells(3, 4)
```

can get the text inside the cell D3 (Row 3, Column 4) of an opened Excel <strike>workbook</strike> worksheet named "Book1". But how to get the way of alignment (i.e. left, right, center or justified) of the cell? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects that govern the horizontal cell alignment. The first is a forced non-default cell alignment that has been applied manually or through code. The second is the `xlGeneral` format which may be right, left or center aligned according to the nature of the data.

```
With objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Book1")
    Select Case .Cells(3, 4).HorizontalAlignment
        Case xlRight        ' equal to -4152
            Debug.Print "The cell is right-aligned."
        Case xlCenter       ' equal to -4108
            Debug.Print "The cell is center-aligned."
        Case xlLeft         ' equal to -4131
            Debug.Print "The cell is left-aligned."
        Case xlGeneral      ' equal to 1
            Select Case Application.Evaluate("TYPE(" & .Cells(3, 4).Address(0, 0, external:=True) & ")")
                Case 1
                    Debug.Print "The cell is right-aligned."
                Case 2
                    Debug.Print "The cell is left-aligned."
                Case 4, 16
                    Debug.Print "The cell is center-aligned."
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print "The cell is part of an array."
            End Select
    End Select
End With
```

Are you sure it is your worksheet and not your workbook that is called *Book1*?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have corrected the word "workbook" in the question.